# Mysql errno:150 on create, after remove of field it works

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I have two tables which should be connected to each other by relations. I created a model in MySQL Workbench but I got an error. After some testing I found something strange, in my opinion.

The tables I want to create (which fails with errno: 150):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `info_paginas` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL ,
    `revision` DECIMAL(10,1) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `revision`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages_roles` (
    `revision` DECIMAL(10,1) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`revision`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_roles_info_paginas2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`revision` )
    REFERENCES `info_paginas` (`revision` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

But this query goes ok (I removed the PK id from the table info_paginas):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `info_paginas` (
    `revision` DECIMAL(10,1) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`revision`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages_roles` (
    `revision` DECIMAL(10,1) NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`revision`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_pages_roles_info_paginas2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`revision` )
    REFERENCES `info_paginas` (`revision` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I don't get whats wrong, exactly the same tables with the same engine but only a PK less. Somebody knows the awnser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to map single-column foreign key to a multiple-column primary key - and that is impossible. You can map multiple column key via foreign key only if your foreign key have **the same** structure - i.e. count of columns and data type for each column.

Alternatively, you should define single-column key, like this:

```
alter table info_paginas add key `byRevision` (`revision`);
```

and then run your second query (in this case you'll get mapping single-column key to single-column key).

Comment: Ok i tried that. It worked thanks :). I tried another table before and it went fine with the same structure. But thanks again :)